# Solving $\ln$ equations with polynomial terms.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I solve the following equation for $x$:

> $\ln(x) -3x+3=0$

Comment: Your last four posts are also problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Generally** there is not an explicit solution to these equations, meaning a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions. For this reason and to calculate the values of the solutions of such equations, numerical analysis and numerical methods come into play.

**But** in your specific case, observe that $x=1$ is a solution to the equation. Now, consider the function:
$$f(x) = \ln x - 3x + 3.$$
By calculating its derivative and studying the properties of the function (monotonicity), you can conclude whether that particular solution is unique or not.

In a wider aspect, solutions of such equations can be expressed via the Lambert $W$ function. You can find more information [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln x-3x+3=0\iff\begin{cases} x>0\\ \ln (xe^{-3x})=-3\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases} x>0\\ xe^{-3x}=e^{-3}\end{cases}\\\iff \begin{cases} x>0\\ -3xe^{-3x}=-3e^{-3}\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases} x>0\\ x=-\frac13W(-3e^{-3})\end{cases}\lor\begin{cases} x>0\\ x=-\frac13W_{-1}(-3e^{-3})\end{cases}$$

$W$ and $W_{-1}$ may be considered because $-3e^{-3}\ge- e^{-1}$. Now, since $-3\le-1$, we have that $W_{-1}(-3e^{-3})=-3$. For the other case, $W(\alpha)$ sends negative numbers to negative numbers and positive numbers to positive numbers, therefore $-\frac13W(-3e^{-3})>0$. Thus

$$x=-\frac{W(-3e^{-3})}{3}\lor x=1$$